# QGIS 2.14.12 Essen / Ubuntu 16.04: Error Numpy/GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, numpy

I am using QGIS 2.14.12 Essen under Ubuntu 16.04. Xenial. My overarching goal is to use the entire QGIS suite, including GRASS, SAGA, Orfeo and TauDEM. In general, QGIS works fine and so does Grass, however, I get some crashes when using SAGA and some python based algorithm. When I start QGIS from the terminal, I get the following output:

```
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Terms of Service / About" under id 243 
ERROR 1: NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.1 but current library version is 1.11

Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Werkzeugkiste" under id 399 
ERROR 4: `/initrd.img' not recognised as a supported file format.

Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action
```

Particulary, error 1 seems to be a problem.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The error message notes that numpy expects GDAL 2.1, but your QGIS has GDAL 1.11

It seems you are using the `qgis/debian xenial` repository. Try the `qgis/ubuntugis xenial` repository with the ubuntugis-unstable ppa which is built against GDAL 2.1.

But be sure to remove the QGIS installation **completely**. Otherwise you will get stuck in broken dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that already did it. I had tried that a couple of times before, however, obviously, I didn't remove it completely. Thanks a lot for that. Nonetheless, I do get q couple of errors related to ERROR 4: /initrd.img: Keine Berechtigung. Most of all, Orfeo obviously can't save its outputs. Possibly, thats comparably easy to solve, can you help out anyway? Some examples: ERROR 4: /tmp/processing0808ccc1678d4ad68ac22abbd3d1a967/4fa15f1ea4d24fb3b868f39e6e85e908/out.tif: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
ERROR 4: /home/andreas/Schreibtisch/output.tif: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Comment: That error is worth a new question.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll open one. You're right, the first question is answered.

Comment: Please think  of accepting the answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers